# How does 'symmetry' of a circuit allow us to find currents when a junction splits into 2 different resistors?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, symmetry, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

The book says what the picture shows.

There's no parallel or series resistors and I could solve it with 4 different currents (if the top blue arrow is i3 and bottom green is i4) but that's a 4 variable simultaneous equation. Instead I'm supposed to see that the respective currents are the same but I don't see how.

The book doesn't say a single thing about applying symmetry to circuits and I'm very confused as the only tools I have after the circuit chapter is parallel and series equivalence, and a triple sim. eq. with one junction rule and two loop rules. This exercise completely threw me off.

Comment: Hint: Think about what happens when you flip the polarity of the voltage source, that is, put the + where the - is and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't tell me anything